# How to correct regular expression

Tags: regex

I have something like this https://regexr.com/3ja39 and the question is: How should I change regexp to get value beetween lot and ohm but without lot and ohm I want to get only value which is beetewm

Comment: What language? Also, you shouldn't parse HTML with regex: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Also, include all the relevant information in your question, not external links.

Comment: Javascript, like in regexr.com

Comment: and I don't know better online html parser

Comment: You simply need to get the contents of the first capture group. What you're seeking is in that value. Use `exec()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression)

Comment: I want use this regex only few times and only online in regexr.com (need get list of resistors values given on page)

Comment: Just copy paste everything into https://regex101.com (it'll show you captures) or use `$1` instead of `$&`

Comment: I always use regex101.com but now I got ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT when I try open this page :(

Comment: Delete your browser history & cookies.

Comment: It's not help I even try two diffrent browser

Comment: It may be down at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Use parenthesis in Regex to capture specific text between other characters, if this is always going to be a numeric between lot- and -ohm you could do something like:
        .*?lot-(\d.*)-ohm.*?

I like this site, it has a great cheat sheet on the regex characters and what they do [Regex Cheatsheet](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/46/c-regular-expressions-cheat-sheet)!

[Javascript Regex](https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/javascript)

Comment: But that's a C# regex cheat sheet. Some of the information in there isn't relevant to JavaScript. Also, it doesn't contain all C# regex tokens, so it's a pretty bad cheat sheet.

Comment: I find it weird that the new cheat sheet you posted shows the quantifier as `{2, 5}` even though that's not valid and it shouldn't have a space `{2,5}`

Comment: It's probably a typo